# Typescript - typing a function that takes an array of string and create an output with strings as keys

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes an array of strings, and creates an object where the strings are it's keys and value is true.

Like so:

```
return keys.reduce((result, key) => {
    result[key] = true;

    return result;
}, {});
```

I'd like to type this function using Typescript, so that when using it it will infer that the return object has keys as the array of strings from the input (let's assume the input is always static)

Anyone know a way to achieve this? I'd like something like this to work:

```
const result = myFunction(['key1', 'key2'])
```

and have TS recognise result as an object with keys: key1 and key2

Thanks to any helpers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function should do the trick ([code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=75&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGIFczCgS3DAvDAHgDkYBTADylLABMIZoAnTMAcwBoYAVMy6umI1IBDGuAA2CGEQDaAXQB8ACgDWpBBABc3AJR4FMNRoB0QmimCklS4cGCcje3AaUBvALAAoGDGN-b9l4+MkZy2lCMKKReAL46nK4xMML0rjAyANIwLNwyYChwAEakjHJhMBFRMHEA3F5eoJCwQhAo4rD4iKjoWOBKMgDkRgCMA5xD6gBMA3J6APRzMGkj4ZGkNYZTq1EbMfWeDeAQIOKkxuIgrEotbVA6QA)):

```
const myFunction = <N extends string, T extends readonly N[]>(keys: T) => keys.reduce(
  (acc, key) => ({
    ...acc,
    [key]: true
  }), {} as { [K in T[number]]: true });

const result = myFunction(['key1', 'key2']) // { key1: true; key2: true; }
```

You can leave out type parameter `N`, when you use `as const` ([code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGIFczCgS3DAvDAHgBUYBTADylLABMIYAnUgQxvABsEZoHMwBzANoBdAHwAKANakEEAFwwiASjyiY02QDomNFMFLjxzYMAA06mStxrxAbwCwAKBgxNb42acvBG4QqgMKKROAL5K5rYhMMz0tjCCANIwfIqCYChwAEakDMJ+MAFBMGEA3E5OoJCwTBAo7LD4iKjoWODiggDkGgCMHeZdMgBMHcLR9JXQKgD0UzBxPf6BpCUWCIOLQSsh5Y4V4BAg7KSa7CD84jV1UEpAA)):

```
const myFunction = <T extends readonly string[]>(keys: T) => {/* as above */ }

const result = myFunction(['key1', 'key2'] as const) // { key1: true; key2: true; }
```

Comment: Oh man this works beautifully! How does one get so damn proficient with Typescript??